# Can the Virgin Galactic's feathered rentry system be used for first stage recovery?

Tags: rockets, falcon-9, recovery, virgin-galactic, first-stage

The stage seperation for Falcon 9's heaviest launch on 28 August 2022 was at approx 75km altitude and at a speed of 8000km/h.

Virgin Galactic's Spaceship two has a max speed of 4000km/h and a max service ceiling of 110km.

Would it be possible theoretically for a first stage to use the feathered reentry system to recover the booster?

Answer (score 4):

Not needed.  The SpaceX Falcon 9 steering fins put drag above center of gravity, guaranteeing a stable descent.  The Virgin Galactic "feathering" system, advertised as a badminton "shuttlecock", does exactly the same thing.